# The second derivative of the characteristic function and the integral of the random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, characteristic-functions

I want to prove that if characteristic function $\bar\mu$ has a second derivative than $$\int_\mathbb{R}|x|^2\mu(dx) < +\infty.$$
I am thinking about how to apply characteristic functions, but I do not know how to do it. May somebody can help me? I would be grateful.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show your working

Comment: To be honest I just recently learned about characteristic functions. and I don't understand them at all.  I don't even know where to start

Comment: Show what you know you think is relevant next please - so we can see what you know

Comment: Thanks, i will do it next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the [second-order central difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) of a function $f$:
$$
\delta_h^2[f](x)=f(x-2h)+f(x+2h)-2f(x).
$$
Then
$$
\delta_h^2[\bar{\mu}](t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{itx}(2i\sin xh)^2\, d\mu(x),
$$
and
$$
\left|\frac{\delta_h^2[\bar{\mu}](0)}{(2h)^2}\right|=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\frac{\sin xh}{h}\right)^2\, d\mu(x).
$$
For each $N>0$,
$$
|\bar{\mu}''(0)|=\lim_{h\to 0}\left|\frac{\delta_h^2[\bar{\mu}](0)}{(2h)^2}\right|\ge \lim_{h\to 0}\int_{-N}^N\left(\frac{\sin xh}{h}\right)^2\, d\mu(x)=\int_{-N}^N x^2\,d\mu(x),
$$
which implies the result.

Comment: Could you please describe in more detail how we got the second order central approximation for the characteristic function, it seems strange to me that a sine appeared there

Comment: I missed a factor of $2$ in the first equation. Otherwise,
\begin{align}
\delta_h^2[\bar{\mu}](t)&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(e^{i(t-2h)x}+e^{i(t+2h)x}-2e^{itx}\right)\, d\mu(x) \\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{itx}\left(e^{-2ihx}+e^{2ihx}-2\right)\, d\mu(x) \\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{itx}2(\cos(2xh)-1)\, d\mu(x) \\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{itx}(2i\sin(xh))^2\, d\mu(x) \quad\because\cos(2xh)=1-2\sin^2(xh)
\end{align}

Comment: I think this line is not correct$$
\left|\frac{\delta_h^2[\bar{\mu}](0)}{(2h)^2}\right|=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\frac{\sin xh}{h}\right)^2\, d\mu(x).
$$ It seems to me instead of $=$ should be $\le$ or am I mistaken?

Comment: Why is that? Plug $t=0$ s.t. $e^{itx}=1$, and notice that $(2i\sin(xh))^2=-(2\sin(xh))^2$.